# Unpacking and building SQL Server 2014 project with VS2012 sqlpackage.exe

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, dacpac, sql-server-2012-datatools, sqlpackage

I've been trying to test whether a project (DB, SSIS, SSAS) built on SQL Server 2014 will be compatible with SQL Server 2012. I've got a `.dproj` packed in dacpac format and when I try to run this from cmd:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Script /SourceFile:"Project.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:DBName /TargetServerName:"DBName /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false /p:RegisterDataTierApplication=true /p:BlockWhenDriftDetected=false /OutputPath:Logs\Output.sql
```

I get a following error:

> *** Could not deploy package. Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Sch
>   ema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure
>   the servic e is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a
>   valid database platform  service.

I created a VM on Azure with SQL Server installed. Apart from that I installed Data Tools for VS 2012. I'm guessing that it might be compatibility problem, but maybe there's a workaround this without changing DT to a higher version? Any patch that could be applied?

Comment: Can you explain why you would do such a thing when later versions of ssdt are available free of charge?

Comment: That's a great question, which should be asked to one of my clients who is very persistant about sticking to 2012. I'm just trying to figure out whether there is a way to do this without upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a more recent dacfx (sqlpackage) or you can copy the DAC folder from a more recent version to the deploy machine and use that instance of `sqlpackage.exe` to deploy.

You can also set the properties in the project itself to target SQL Server 2012 and it will validate that the T-SQL is correct for SQL Server 2012 and let you deploy to it.

There were lots of fixes between `sqlpackage` 2012 and 2014 so I would move them onto a newer version of `sqlpackage` even if you still target a SQL Server 2012 box.

This is only for dacpacs, not sure about the other projects.